# How I can do a send message task inside a dispatcher.run_async() using python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, asynchronous, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I develop a telegram bot using the python-telegram-bot module. I attempt to run a function without executing it using `dispatcher.run_async(myfunction)` but how I can do a task for example sending a message from inside the `dispatcher.run_async()`?

I have all the users id in my database. And this is the snippet of my code.

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater

def myfunction():
    # bot.send_message(text='Hello, World',chat_id=<user_id>)

def main():
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("TOKEN")

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.run_async(myfunction)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: So you want to send a message from inside `myFunction` ?

Comment: yes, does it possible for doing that?

Comment: Do you want `myFunction` to run when the bot starts, or on a received command?

Comment: I'm trying to run a function at the start and make it asynchronously. But I can't find any function or method for sending the message from inside the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the intended way, but you can pass the bot the the function by passing it to `run_async`:

```py
dispatcher.run_async(myFunction, updater.bot)

def myfunction(bot):
    bot.send_message(text='Hello, World',chat_id=123456789)
```

---

```py
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater

def myfunction(bot):
    bot.send_message(text='Hello, World',chat_id=123456789)

def main():
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("<MY-BOT-TOKEN>")

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.run_async(myfunction, updater.bot)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It seems doesn't work if you put a while loop with the bot sending message inside. It will never make it to the next line after `dispatcher.run_async(myfunction, updater.bot)` because the bot still working inside the loop. But, it helps me for the first part anyway. 